# Why are the mixcolumns in AES in a fixed order? Can the order be changed?

Tags: aes, algorithm-design

Almost the same question as my “[Why are the shiftrows in AES in a fixed order? Can the order be changed?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/38090/12164)” but this time it’s about the AES ***MixColumns***.

Why are the `mixcols` fixed? Can we keep adequate security by changing the order? If not 'any' order, what about some other arrangements? Or is this arrangement the only one suitable?

Comment: Related: [What would happen to AES if we replaced MixColumns with ShiftColumns?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34928/12164) and [AES with shuffleBytes instead of shiftRows](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35771/12164)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "order"? Each column is "mixed" independently using the same operation. If you are talking about the MixColumns *matrix*, of course you can change it, but

1. the operation defined by the matrix must be bijective;
2. the matrix should have low linear and differential branching numbers (optimal in case of the AES MixColumns).