# How does AES introduce confusion and diffusion?

Tags: aes, diffusion

I know that in AES the shift-rows and mix-columns operations introduce diffusion, but I don't understand how they create diffusion. Also, I know the add-round-key operation creates confusion, but I don't understand how it creates confusion by simply XORing the round key with the columns of the state matrix.

Answer (score 11):

Put simply:

- The add key layer ensures the encryption function is only computable by someone who knows the key

  - Adds some confusion because the key is (psuedo) random
- The subBytes s-box layer creates confusion

  - each symbol is mapped to another symbol in a way that impedes common methods of cryptanalysis (high resistance to linear and differential cryptanalysis)
- The shiftRows and mixColumns operations combine to provide full diffusion over the course of 2 rounds

  - The state is a 4x4 grid of 8-bit words
  - mixColumns operates vertically on each 4 word/32-bit column

    - One bits difference in any word in the input column will spread to multiple places in multiple words in the output column
  - shiftRows ensures that over the course of successive rounds different words are grouped up as inputs to the mixColumn function
  - There's a good answer that is slightly more specific [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34472/29554)

For more information, consult the book on the [design of Rijndael](https://autonome-antifa.org/IMG/pdf/Rijndael.pdf), or maybe try one of the handy [diagrams](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) or [animations](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ezivkovm/nastava/rijndael_animacija.swf) that exist.